# Getting events out of Facebook?

Tags: drupal, facebook

Is it possible to get event info from Facebook so the following is true:

1. Add events that are not just your own events (i.e. search for general events and not just grab the events you have set as attended by your user)
2. Specify criteria (e.g. get all events for one specific city)

If this is possible, what should one use? where do you start?

Comment: It seems like it would be impossible to access general events because of facebook's security settings.

Comment: Is it possible to at least access your own events?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Graph API search to find events that are public, provided that you provide a search query. Here is an example query, you won't need to get a user access token to run this, however using one is recommended as Facebook are [introducing that as a requirement in July](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#july-2012):

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=conference&type=event&access_token=ACCESSTOKEN`

Once you have the Event ID, you can query to https://graph.facebook.com/EVENTID and use that to RSVP to the event [by sending a POST to the `attending` connection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#attending) with an access token that has `rsvp_events` permission.

It will not be possible to just search for events in a particular city, however once you have an Event ID list, you can go through those events and only pick those with matching locations. Most Event location fields are freeform though, so they are unlikely to stick to a common format.